# Does deleting Linux user also delete password?

Tags: linux, unix

Does deleting user with command deluser  deletes the password associated with that username in Linux?

Comment: Please explain... what would it mean if a user were deleted but their password still existed? Do you mean, "can the password of the ex-user be recovered forensically"? Or do you mean "If the same username were created again, would they receive the same password"? (I suspect the answer is no in both cases.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the man page:

> The userdel command modifies the system account files, deleting all entries that refer to login_name.

So, yes. Again, the man page states it will modify these files:

> /etc/group
>       Group account information.
>   /etc/login.defs
>       Shadow password suite configuration.
>   /etc/passwd
>       User account information.
>   /etc/shadow
>       Secure user account information.

The password is (usually) stored in `/etc/shadow`.